# How can I compare images in a PictureBox and an ImageList?

Tags: c#, .net, image, picturebox, imagelist

I am using an `ImageList` and a `PictureBox` in my application. I am loading the image in the `PictureBox` dynamically from an image in the `ImageList`. I need to check whether the image in the `PictureBox` and a certain index of an image in the `ImageList` are equal. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare Image objects with C# .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384967/how-to-compare-image-objects-with-c-net)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `Image` class doesn't implement the `==` operator or the `Equals` method, which means it inherits the default implementation from the `Object` class that simply checks if the object references are the same. It turns out that this will fail, even if an image is assigned to the `PictureBox` directly out of your `ImageList`.

So, you'll need to implement your own logic to check if the images are the same. There are a couple of different approaches. You could either load each of the two images into a byte array and do a byte-by-byte comparison, or you could loop through the two images pixel-by-pixel and compare their colors. Of course, both of these methods are going to be anywhere from relatively to unreasonably slow. You could potentially optimize either by simply comparing the dimensions first (the `Image` object does provide a [`Size` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.size.aspx) that returns its dimensions) and returning False if they are not equal, but this probably won't work in your case, since all of the images in the `ImageList` will have the same dimensions.

If it were me, I'd save myself the trouble and just keep the index of the image in the `ImageList` that I assigned to the `PictureBox` somewhere in a class-level variable...

If you're still resolute despite my warnings, see the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384967/how-to-compare-image-objects-with-c-net).

Comment: i know that there is a possibility to handle in class-level variable but i want to know where there is any option to check (i.e., properties, etc.,)

Comment: @Kumaran: I don't understand what you mean. There's no property or method built in to compare two images. It's not part of the .NET Framework, and the first paragraph of my answer attempts to explain why the two things you might think to try won't actually work. If you want to be able to compare two image objects, you'll need to implement your own solution, as the second part of my answer explains.

Comment: I did attempt my solution, as well as a number of others and I stand corrected and apologize. You're absolutely correct; there doesn't appear to be a direct way to compare images in this scenario. +1

Comment: @SnOrfus: No need to apologize! Like I said, I first thought the same thing you did. It would be *far* simpler and more convenient if that would work. There's an interesting discussion on that subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762310/whats-the-reason-both-image-and-bitmap-classes-dont-implement-a-custom-equality

Answer (score 1):

Dude instead of going for a image list. just go with the list box.
I have a programmed a tool in C# wherein it takes 2 inputs from user. First being the folder which contains bulk of images and second being the input image ( whose similar images u need to separate from the bulk of images.

1. when to take the input
   folder. List out the contents of the
   folder in the listBox i.e;   the
   path of every image in the folder.
2. now since you have the path
   of every image in the folder, take
   images one by one into a Image for
   Bitmap and compare it with the input
   image you have given earlier. Use
   any methods or similarity metric to
   find out to what extent or what %
   the images are same.
3. Note the %'s and then
   separate them from the bulk of
   images.( this is again easy since
   you have the path of every image in
   the folder.)

I don't know to what extent i made myself clear. I hope this was of some help to you. good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is absolute solution

**Assign a value to image.**

**Tag differently for each image**

That's the solution then you can compare based on tag value